# How to restore duplicity directories that have spaces in the names?

Tags: linux, duplicity

I have used Duplicity to create encrypted compressed archives of some of my directories. I can extract from the archives any directory I like, except when the directory name has spaces in it.

The command I run is:

```
duplicity --file-to-restore 'Clients/new client' file://mnt/backups/DUPLICITY/   TEMPDIR/
```

The error I get is: `No backup chains foud` which is a general error that can mean anything. And oh, there is no typos in the command.

I tried using --force, using double quotes, using single quotes, nothing works.  Also, escaping spaces like

```
'clients/new\ client/backups/DUPLICITY
```

does not work

So far, I can only extract directorynames that do not have spaces. I cannot believe that Duplicity cannot one way or the other handle whitespaces in directory names.

Any tips or hints?

Comment: I was merely asking to get more details for others to be able to help you. Thank you for providing it. I edited it into the question, which is what should usually be done when giving more info. I personally have never used Duplicity, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

what's you duplicity version?

try restoring the parent directory that has no space in the path. does that work?

if not file a bug on
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity

..ede/duply.net

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).